# Burmester Desmedt Key agreement. Is the division a floating point one or an integer one

Tags: key-exchange

As I look upon Burmester Desmedt algorithm:

[image]

I notice that the intermediate key $K_i$ is getting calculated as:

$K_i=(k_{i+1}/k_{i-1})^{x_i} \mod p$

Thus I wonder wheher the division $k_{i+1}/k_{i-1}$ should result an integer of a floating point number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Thus I wonder whether the division $k_{i+1}/k_{i-1}$ should result an integer of a floating point number.

An integer.

Specifically, this computation is done modulo $p$; that is, the result of this division is the value $d$ such that $d \cdot k_{i-1} \equiv k_{i+1} \pmod p$.

One way to find this $d$ is to compute the multiplicative inverse of $k_{i-1}$ modulo $p$ (for example, using the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), and then multiply that inverse with $k_{i+1}$ (again, modulo $p$)

Comment: What I actually do is I permform the division with OpenSSL's BigInt so I wanted to clarify wheher is this way to go.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas: you mean `BN_div`?  No, that's wrong; you need to do division in the field $\mathbb{Z}_p$, not in the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ (rounded down).  Instead, see `BN_mod_inverse` and `BN_mod_mul`

Comment: So I calculate inverse of the $k_{i-1}$ with `BN_mod_inverse` And then I multiply it with `BN_mod_mul`?

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas: by George, I think you've got it...